# White screen on front page only

Tags: server, debug, frontpage, wp-debug

I've got the famous white screen, but only on my home page. Deeper pages load just fine. I moved my `themes` directory to `themes-old` and made a new `themes` directory that only has twentyten in it. I changed my theme to twenty ten. I don't have any plugins enabled, but I moved my plugins directory and created a new, empty plugins directory.

I turned debugging on.

I'm at a total loss here. I did make some theme tweaks today, but I already restored the back up of my theme which didn't help, and anyway I've now set twentyten as my theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure that the `index.php` will be loaded first add the following line to your `.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

This tells Apache to ignore an `index.html` if an `index.php` exists.

Comment: Removing the errant index.html works better, but this is a good alternate solution.

Comment: I have had the white screen of death on several different sites now, and each time I seem to need a different fix. This one worked for me _this time_ ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because I somehow dropped a file called "index.html" in my WordPress install.

How'd I find out? I created a completely fresh installation and used `diff` to compare them.

Comment: Always add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` to your wp-config.php during dev.

Comment: That doesn't help if `index.html` is overriding `index.php`

Comment: Shure it helps: You know that not a function is killing your output.

Comment: OMG! I always look over this kind f stuff. Somehow, an index.html ended up in the repo, whitepaging the frontend :-P